# How dynamically transform my "Object" to List in ng-model at view

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to transform my object to list dynamically, so I'm building at view instead of declaring at controller.

I don't want to declare like this: `custom_fields.title_field.type_text_field = []` because the `title_field` is built dynamic, it could be any kind of text like `full_name`

My json as is:

```
     "custom_fields":{  
        "title_dynamic_generate_field":{  
           "type_text_field":{  
              "name":"John",
              "first_name":"Wick"
           },
            "type_boolean_field":{
                "is_badass": true,
                "is_good_movie": true
           },
            "type_select_field": {
                "this_select": 1,
                "i_got_this": "nope i didnt got this"
            }
        },
```

And to be:

```
     "custom_fields":{  
        "title_dynamic_generate_field":{  
           "type_text_field":[{  
              "name":"John",
              "first_name":"Wick"
           }],
            "type_boolean_field":[{
                "is_badass": true,
                "is_good_movie": true
           }],
            "type_select_field": [{
                "this_select": 1,
                "i_got_this": "nope i didnt got this"
            }]
        },
```

the object I'm trying to transform into array is `type_text_field` which can be dynamic too, like `type_date_field` or `type_select_field` and so on.

My `ng-model` is like this:

```
ng-model="objectApp.application.applicant.custom_fields[layout.dynamic_title][input.type][input.variable]"
```

the `[input.type]` is that I'm trying to transform into array, how can I achieve this? I tried to use `$index`, but got strange results.

Comment: I like you question it's useful, thanks

Comment: please can you improve your question by add the multi objects and how you want convert them? it's much better than 1 object.

Comment: see my edit! thanks!

Comment: If you ask me you need to change your model, this model is not good for the application

Comment: why is not good for the app?

Comment: because we can create new model for optimum the codes, for example we can create object as `inputs` which includes all inputs but different types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it by 2 solutions:

> There is a question about your task:
>
> **?** how you want handle if we have more than one `type_text_field` in `title_dynamic_generate_field`? because you want to convert it to `"type_text_field":[{},...]`

**however my answers about the question are:**

1. If we know what's the dynamic `params` which we want to send theme as `json`, i mean if we know what is the key of `title_dynamic_generate_field` or `type_text_field`, we do as this sample:

   ```
   var data = {
     "custom_fields": {
       dynamicParamIs1: 'title_dynamic_generate_field',
       dynamicParamIs2: 'type_text_field',
       "title_dynamic_generate_field": {
           "type_text_field": {
               "name": "John",
               "first_name": "Wick"
           }
       }
     }
   }

   var paramHelper1 = json.custom_fields[json.custom_fields.dynamicParamIs1];
   var paramHelper2 = json.custom_fields.dynamicParamIs2;

   var solutionA = function (object, as) {
      var array = [];

      for (var key in object) {
        var newObject = object[key];
        array.push(newObject);
      }

      object[as] = array;
   }

   solutionA(paramHelper1, paramHelper2);
   ```

> We changed a model of our `json` which can help us to detect (find) the keys

2. If we don't know what is the dynamic `params` are, we do as this:

   ```
   var data = {
     "custom_fields": {
       "title_dynamic_generate_field": {
           "type_text_field": {
               "name": "John",
               "first_name": "Wick"
           }
       }
     }
   }

   var solutionB = function (json) {
      var array = [];
      for (var key in json) {
          var j1 = json[key];
          for (var key2 in j1) {
              var j2 = j1[key2];
              for (var key3 in j2) {
                  var fullObject = j2[key3];
                  array.push(fullObject);
                  j2[key3] = array;
              }
          }
      }
   }

   solutionB(data);
   ```

> This sample is manual which we use nested `for` to detect the `keys` name

Comment: Since everything is dynamic, except `custom_fields`, i don't know which params are, because it come from some server... but the answer 2 is quite viable, when I get hands on it I will check it out.

Comment: If our objects is always the same as i see, we can handle it by `solutionB`